# Read feed with PHP correct encoding?

Tags: php, rss

I'm using the following code to read a RSS feed. The problem is that I get wrong encoding. The code is in a file with UTF-8 encoding. Is there anything else I have to do to get it right?

```
$feed_url = "http://lujanenlinea.com.ar/noticias/feed";
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  

echo "<div class='rss-container'>";
echo "<ul class='rss-content'>";
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {  
    echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";  
}  
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Which encoding is the feed url?

Comment: Maybe you have this problem: [UTF-8 issue with file_get_contents ](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#85008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()`